# dynamic keys of firebase custom claims in real-time database security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, firebase-security

I add a dynamic json key to an user's custom claims and i want to use that key/value to allow user to write on a node.

Ex: Here is how i do it using the firebase admin sdk for nodejs.

```js
// I get the user object
admin.auth().getUser(uid).then(userRecord => {
    let claims = userRecord.customClaims; // current user claims

    // I add the new key/value to the current claims object
    // shop.id is obtained with DatabaseReference.push()
    //Note: I prepend a 'B' to prevent a JSON key starting with '-'
    claims[`B${shop.id}`] = someData[userRecord.uid] === 'manager' ? 1 : 0;

    // I update the user claims
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, claims);
});
```

In the realtime database security rules i have a node where i control the write permission with the following rule:

No other rule out of the mNode scope

```json
{
    "mNode":{
        "$shopId":{
            ".read": "auth.uid!==null"
            ".write":"auth.token['B'+$shopId]===1"
        }
    }
}
```

On android i try to write on the path.

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("mNode").child("theShopIdUsedInClaims").setValue(t)
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                listener.onSuccess();
            }else {
               listener.onError(task.getException(),ref.toString());
            }
        });
```

The claims are successfully set to the user's token. I check them by 'stringifying' the user's claims object. But the write access is not granted.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Please edit the question to show all relevant code, including the code you use the set the custom claim, the full set of security rules, and the query that doesn't get protected the way you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have my computer at the moment so I'll do it later.

Comment: Hello, i updated the question. @DougStevenson

Comment: I don't know, maybe try using boolean true/false instead of 1/0?

Comment: Can you post the printed claims, as well as the write error you're receiving?